# python unzip files below the root folder

Tags: python, root, unzip, directory

i would like to unzip all the folders and files of an archive below the root folder, i have archive named abc.zip which gives me files as abc/xyz/ abc/123.jpg abc/xyz1/ , i just want to extract xyz/ , 123.jpg and xyz1/ in the CWD

i use below code to extract a file, but would need help on how to omit the root folder of the list

def unzip_artifact( local_directory, file_path ):

```
fileName, ext = os.path.splitext( file_path )

if ext == ".zip":

Downloadfile = basename(fileName) + ext

    print 'unzipping file ' + Downloadfile

    try:
    zipfile.ZipFile(file_path).extractall(local_directory)

    except zipfile.error, e:
        print "Bad zipfile: %s" % (e)
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a more complex (and therefore more customizable) way to unzip. Instead of using the 'extractall' method, you must extract each files separately with the 'extract' method. Then you will be able to change the destination directory, omitting archive's sub-directories.

Here is your code with the modification you needed :

```
def unzip_artifact( local_directory, file_path ):

    fileName, ext = os.path.splitext( file_path )
    if ext == ".zip":
        Downloadfile = fileName + ext
        print 'unzipping file ' + Downloadfile

        try:
            #zipfile.ZipFile(file_path).extractall(local_directory) # Old way
            # Open the zip
            with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path) as zf:
                # For each members of the archive
                for member in zf.infolist():
                    # If it's a directory, continue
                    if member.filename[-1] == '/': continue
                    # Else write its content to the root
                    with open(local_directory+'/'+os.path.basename(member.filename), "w") as outfile:
                        outfile.write(zf.read(member))

        except zipfile.error, e:
            print "Bad zipfile: %s" % (e)
        return
```